# New Paragraph in Gscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't figure out how to start a new paragraph when trying to define my email body.

I've been messing around with `<br/>`, but I can't get it to work.

```
 var body = "Dear " + row[1] +  "<br />  In order to comply with statutory 
 requirements"
```

The message comes out good with regards to the row[1] and the text I have (only a snippet shown), but I can't get the second sentence, 'in order to comply...' to start off as a new paragraph. How do I do this?

Comment: Weird, but when I put <br /> in my comment above it actually made a new line, and didn't show the actual text itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for an email and you actually want to use HTML tags for the email body, look into the [`htmlBody` option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) when sending the email.

If all you want is a new line in your email, just use `\n` for each new line you want in the email body.